# XBAP script interop fails

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, internet-explorer, xbap

I'm writing a small iframe-hosted XBAP that needs to interact with the host page.
I've first wrote a small POC to see that all I need is possible.

Here's the code of the page constructor:

```
Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()
        Try
            Dim scriptObject = BrowserInteropHelper.HostScript
            scriptObject.alert("blablabla")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Sign error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

The "alert" line throws next exception:

```
   System.TypeAccessException: Attempt by method 'DynamicClass.CallSite.Target(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure, System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite, System.Object, System.Object ByRef)' to access type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite`1<Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.IDOUtils+SiteDelegate1>' failed.

   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Object& )

   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.IDOUtils.CreateRefCallSiteAndInvoke(CallSiteBinder Action, Object Instance, Object[] Arguments)

   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.IDOBinder.IDOCall(IDynamicMetaObjectProvider Instance, String MemberName, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Boolean[] CopyBack, Boolean IgnoreReturn)

   at SignVerify.Web.XBAP.Page1..ctor()
```

This happens in IE 64-bit, with IE 32-bit the whole XBAP fails to load (even before the alert line).

Thanks allot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OKay, I've understood my mistake.
Should have marked the application as full-trust, this way it works perfectly.